# Cannot send emails with STMP Postfix on port 587?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I have followed this guide line by line: https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

Finally got emails to be received but I cannot send them and all I get is connecting to mail.. I am using the Claws mail client and it lets me login and receive emails but just not send them. I set it to use port 587 but it just hangs on connecting when sending

Here is my master.cf:

```
##
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
```

and I cannot see anything in the logs /var/log/mail.log which says what is going on. Port 587, 465 and 25 are open in the firewall as well.

Where do I go from here to debug this?

UPDATE:
I am able to connect via telnet on the server using port 587, postfix is running but I just cannot connect using the Claws Mail client when sending, it receives mail fine, even if I send an email from a Gmail account.

Comment: telnet your.smtp.hostname 587 can you see the smtp banner?

Comment: I tried telnet mail.hostname.com 587 and all I get is "Trying <Server_IP>..." Connection timed out, the port 587 is set to be allowed in UFW?

Comment: As I supposed, it's even the local or gateway's firewall blocking your connections.

Comment: I am able to use the Claws Mail client to receive mail but just not send, I even connect to the same hostname address and it works for receiving. What would I do now?

Comment: Try iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: What type of network are you in? Who is got admin access to the firewall/router/gateway?

Comment: Me, I have full access. Postfix & dovecot are all setup on the same server.

Comment: What is the ip address of default gateway in your network.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but when i try to use port 995 instead, as that is the port used in the guide I followed, inside the mail.log it shows `dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs)...`

Comment: Telnet allows me to connect to port 995?

Comment: Don't bother with port 995. Outgoing mail uses SMTP which is ports 25 and 587. Try turning off SELinux. Try turning off your firewall.  Check if postfix is even running with `sudo service postfix status`. See if you can telnet in from the server itself, i.e, `telnet localhost 25`

Comment: Ok well the guide I followed setup Dovecot to use port 995 and 993 but I never had to set port 587 or 25 anywhere, is that wrong? Also yes telnet on the server allows me to connect to 587...

Comment: Please use the comments to improve your question!

Comment: Those are the default ports for SMTP; you set them up by default when you installed postfix.  We're just troubleshooting outgoing mail, right?  You said you were able to receive email, so it sounds like Dovecot and ports 995 (POP3) and 993 (IMAP) are squared away. Are you able to telnet to port 587 (SMTP Submission) as well as port 25 (SMTP)?

Comment: Yes both 25 and 587 work using telnet localhost <port> Correct, its just outgoing mail being is issue here.

Comment: I tried to use ports 25, 465 and 587 to send using smtp with ssl and still no luck :(

Comment: Port 25 is for real email servers to talk to other real email servers like when gmail is trying to deliver your mail to postfix.  People who want to use Thunderbird to send mail via their own Postfix smtp server should be using port 465 (SSL/TLS) or port 587 (STARTLS).  In the first case the entire session is encrypted and in the second you can use telnet or netcat to get a banner until you issue STARTTLS.  But you can use openssl to do the STARTTLS for you from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your router or your isp is blocking outgoing connections to port 587. As you did "iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT", its not the local firewall for sure. I don't think disabling selinux might help as even telent returns a connection timeout.

Comment: That is a bold assumption based on little fact. I have 2 servers running in the same data center and hosted by the same cloud provider.  Both have postfix.  They can talk to each other all day long on ports 25 and on ports 465.  But when I try to connect to one of them from the other on port 587, the session hangs before postfix even sends a banner.  I have debugged the system calls and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong other than Postfix is broken on the Submission service.  And it isn't a firewall because the server logs show the connection comes through and then postfix goes crickets.